# Powershell: move directory structure - if file exists compare the file modification date-time and append date-time to the name of the older file

Tags: powershell, append, move, filecompare

I need to move a whole directory structure over an existent directory structure which can be probably 90% similar.
The files needed to be moved might have identical name correspondents in the directory target.
It would be needed to be made a comparison of the same named files and to rename the one older with the date-name appended to the file name.

So:    if `source\dir1\file1` is **older** than `target\dir1\file1` then rename `source\dir1\file1` to `source\dir1\file1_mod-date-time` and move to `target\dir1`

Similarly:   if `source\dir1\file1` is **newer** than `target\dir1\file1` then rename `target\dir1\file1` to `target\dir1\file1_mod-date-time` and move `source\dir1\file1` to `target\dir1\`

If there is no similar file in destination folder just move it there - and create a new sub-directory if not existent.

I am novice at Powershell and I tried pieces of this to make it work, but no success.

Any help would be VERY appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `if($(Get-Item file1).creationtime -lt $(Get-Item file2).creationtime){}` start with this :)

Comment: I'll try to put something together

Comment: Try to work with foreach loops. This way you can loop through all the files in one folder and do stuff with them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7